# AWS Annotations Framework Input Parameters for C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm having trouble getting a Lambda function written using the AWS Annotations Framework to accept input parameters. This is the article I'm using: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-net-annotations-lambda-framework-preview/, but it only goes so far. When I publish the functions to Amazon and test clicking the TEST button, the input parameters aren't populated.

This is my function:

```
[LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]
        [LambdaFunction()]
        [HttpApi(LambdaHttpMethod.Get, "/add/{x}/{y}")]
        public int Add(int x, int y, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogInformation($"{x} plus {y} is {x + y}");
            return x + y;
        }
```

and this is the Event JSON within the AWS test harness

[image]

The log shows that the parameters have no value:

> 2022-05-09T10:47:02.435Z  51291252-f7cb-4a1e-9f4a-f7aebdec6b02    **info  0
> plus 0 is 0**

I'm using this as an example, I don't actually need a calculator, but I do need to pass input parameters from an Amazon Connect contact flow and I will be passing in parameters like this:

[image]

I've spent a few days Googling and reading articles, but so far I've not found anything that helps, so any assistance is gratefully received!

Comment: I suggest, as this is still prerelease software and subject to change, to open an issue in the AWS Lambda .NET repository and ask the developers there: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet. However looking at your code sample, x and y would be expected to the in the request path, not in the body.

Comment: @MartinCostello - The Contact Flow UI does not allow you to specify a request path, and I've re-run the function with extra logging. The body is null, so I'm definitely doing something wrong in the way I submit the parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `HttpApi` attribute exposes the Lambda function as a REST API called via some http client. Amazon Connect invokes your Lambda function directly using its own event object documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html#function-contact-flow. In .NET the event object is represented as the `Amazon.Lambda.ConnectEvents.ContactFlowEvent` type from the `Amazon.Lambda.ConnectEvents` NuGet package.

Currently the `Amazon.Lambda.Annotations` has support for breaking up the HTTP API event object to follow typical .NET REST patterns. We haven't done that for other types of event sources like Connect, although this is something we want to do.

You can still use `Amazon.Lambda.Annotations` for your use case to get the dependency injection and syncing CloudFormation template features by using just the `LambdaFunction` attribute and then having your function take in the Connect event object. Something like this.

```
[LambdaFunction()]
public IDictionary<string, string> ProcessConnectContactFlow(Amazon.Lambda.ConnectEvents.ContactFlowEvent contactFlowEvent)
{
    // Process the event

    var response = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "Name", "CustomerName" },
        { "Address", "1234 Main Road" },
        { "CallerType", "Patient" }
    };

    return response;
}
```

Comment: thanks, Norm. I got there in the end with this:

        
        var result = new
        {
            resultCode = resultCode,
            custID = custID,
            firstName = firstName, 
            surname = surname,
            dob =   dob.ToString("ddMMyy")
        };